# App Keeps crashing after clicking on a list item instead of launching another activity

Tags: android, string, listview, android-studio, crash

I'm making a menu app for a restaurant.
I just want the first page to be a list of categories, which each category contains a list of menu with title, description, and price.

I have linked each category to new activity pages already, and everything works fine until I modified the page(just starting with the first menu category), it crashes every time I click the first category that has been modified. The rest of the categories still work.

Thank you for your help!

This is my MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.jj.landscapemenu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView List;
String[] memeTitles;
String[] memeDescriptions;
int[] images={R.drawable.smallplates, R.drawable.lunch, R.drawable.streetfood, R.drawable.alltimefav, R.drawable.vegetarian, R.drawable.sideorder, R.drawable.dessert, R.drawable.drinks, R.drawable.happyhour};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    memeTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    memeDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

    List= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categories);
    LandscapeMenuAdapter adapter=new LandscapeMenuAdapter(this, memeTitles, images, memeDescriptions);
    List.setAdapter(adapter);
    List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main4Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 2);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main5Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 3);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main6Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 4);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main7Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 5);
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main8Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 6);
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main9Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 7);
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main10Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 8);
            }
        }
        } );
}

static class LandscapeMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titleArray;
String[] descriptionArray;
LandscapeMenuAdapter(Context c,String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc)
{
    super(c,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView,titles);
    this.context=c;
    this.images=imgs;
    this.titleArray=titles;
    this.descriptionArray=desc;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)         context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent, false);

    ImageView myImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView myTitle= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView myDescription= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

    return row;
}
}}
```

This is my strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">LandscapeMenu</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

<string-array name="titles">
    <item>Small Plates</item>
    <item>Lunch</item>
    <item>Street Food</item>
    <item>Bai Tong All Time Favorites</item>
    <item>Vegetarian Menu</item>
    <item>Side Orders</item>
    <item>Desserts</item>
    <item>Drinks</item>
    <item>Happy Hour Menu</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="descriptions">
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
    <item> </item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="titles2">
    <item>Fresh Rolls</item>
    <item>Grilled Pork Platter</item>
    <item>Crab Wontons</item>
    <item>Fried Tofu</item>
    <item>Grilled Beef</item>
    <item>Spare Ribs</item>
    <item>Sai Gok E San</item>
    <item>Moo Dade Deaw</item>
    <item>Tod Mun Pla</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="descriptions2">
    <item>Prawns, BBQ pork, cilantro, bean sprout, carrots, lettuce, and rice vermicelli wrapped in soft rice skin. Served with our famous peanut sauce.</item>
    <item>Thai grilled marinated pork on a skewer served with sticky rice.</item>
    <item>Crispy-fried wontons stuffed with crab meat and cream cheese. Served with plum sauce.</item>
    <item>Deep-fried tofu, served with plum sauce sprinkled with ground peanuts.</item>
    <item>Tender slices of grilled steak served with our homemade chili dipping sauce.</item>
    <item>Deep fry marinated pork spare ribs. Served with a spicy Sriracha chili sauce.</item>
    <item> </item>
    <item>Pork strips marinated in a sugar and salt brine, then deep frying them to a flavorful golden brown.</item>
    <item>Homemade, fried fishcakes, served with a cucumber-plum sauce topped with crushed peanuts.</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="price2">
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
    <item>$00.00</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jj.landscapemenu.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/woodbackground">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/categories"
android:layout_width="584dp"
android:layout_height="814dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/smallplates" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Plates"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Main2Activity.java

```
package com.example.jj.landscapemenu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView List;
String[] memeTitles2;
String[] memeDescriptions2;
String[] memePrice2;
int[] images={R.drawable.freshrolls, R.drawable.moopingbig, R.drawable.crabwontons, R.drawable.friedtofu, R.drawable.grilledbeef, R.drawable.spareribs, R.drawable.saigokesan, R.drawable.moodadedeaw, R.drawable.todmunpla};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Resources res = getResources();
    memeTitles2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles2);
    memeDescriptions2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions2);

    List= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categories);
    SmallPlatesAdapter adapter=new SmallPlatesAdapter(this, memeTitles2, images, memeDescriptions2, memePrice2);
    List.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}

class SmallPlatesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titleArray;
String[] descriptionArray;
String[] priceArray;
SmallPlatesAdapter(Context c,String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc, String[] prc)
{
    super(c,R.layout.single_row2,R.id.textView3,titles);
    this.context=c;
    this.images=imgs;
    this.titleArray=titles;
    this.descriptionArray=desc;
    this.priceArray=prc;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row2,parent, false);

    ImageView myImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    TextView myTitle= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView myDescription= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TextView myPrice= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
    myPrice.setText(priceArray[position]);

    return row;
}
}
```

This is my single_row2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/freshrolls" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jj.landscapemenu.Main2Activity"
android:background="@drawable/woodbackground">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/smallplates"
    android:layout_width="585dp"
    android:layout_height="873dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jj.landscapemenu">

<supports-screens android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main4Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main5Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main6Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main7Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main8Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main9Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main10Activity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Edited List to list (created an error)
and Intent (no problems)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFTKD.jpg)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post the error log in Android Studio it is by default a tab at the bottom called Android Monitor. I suspect your activity2 is not defined in the manifest.

Comment: There is no error in my Android Monitor tab. It works on the tablet just fine except when I click the first item on the list, it crashes. How to define activity2?

Comment: If it crash there is an error log showing... Without seeing that it's hard to help.

Comment: I see. Is it just not compatible to my device?

Comment: I think that in Main2Activity.java, you have missed, memePrice2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.price2); Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess since there's no crash log.

Is Main2Activity declared in your AndroidManifest.xml?
You need to replace this:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
```

with this:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
```

This is also wrong:

```
List= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categories);
SmallPlatesAdapter adapter=new SmallPlatesAdapter(this, memeTitles2, images, memeDescriptions2, memePrice2);
List.setAdapter(adapter);
```

List is an object, you need to create an instance of it.

```
List list = ....
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still does not work. Once I changed it into List list, it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
ListView list;
```

instead of

```
ListView List;
```

and Write

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
```

Comment: After I changed List to list it gave me an error. I have changed the Intent to what you said, but stil crashes.

Comment: please add screenshot of log file where you got exactly error

Comment: @Narenda Sorathiya I have added the error image in my post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change List to list wherever you used

Comment: OK, Send Screenshot of logcat